# Galleria Folio Theme in Internet Explorer 7

Tags: internet-explorer-7, galleria

Galleria Folio Theme is working fine on Internet Explorer 8 and 9.

However in IE7, the fullscreen mode behaves weirdly: it displays the footer, it rollover on the left sidebar, it displays the Menu on rollover of the top of the image, it displays the Header.

The next, previous and close buttons also do not appear as expectedly.

Answer (score 0):

I downloaded the latest galleria.js file and works fine now..